# Office Addin: Load custom properties on saved events

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins

I am currently devlopping an addin for Outlook and i have to set and read custom properties from an event.
It works perfectly for setting and reading custom properties for a non saved event (when i am creating it), but, once the event is saved and i try to read custom properties, I got this error :

```
{
"error": {
    "code": 9020,
    "message": "Une erreur interne s’est produite.",
    "name": "GenericResponseError"
},
"status": "failed",
"value": null
}
```

Here is my code:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.loadCustomPropertiesAsync(function (_customPropsResult) {
if (_customPropsResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Failed) {
    // Deal with the error
    // my error is here
}

let customProps = _customPropsResult.value;
let myValue = customProps.get('myPropertyName');
})
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Could you provide the platform(s) and build number(s) of Outlook that you're seeing this error on?

Comment: I'm on windows and i'm using office 365

Comment: Could you be more specific? For example, I'm currently using Outlook 2016 for Windows Version 1707 (Build 8305.1000 Click-toRun). We have a lot of builds in flight with new revisions published each month, understanding which build your seeing the error helps quite a bit.

Comment: I'm using office 365 online, so is there a build number ?
On desktop i'm using outlook 2016 MSO (16.0.8067.2115) 32bits for Windows but i'm not using my addin on desktop.

Comment: @AnthonyLeGal to find the version of Outlook Web that you are using, you can either right-click and click "inspect" on Outlook, or hit F12 (in Chrome.) Click on Sources, choose r4.res.office365.com, and open the owa/prem folder. You should see a folder with a version 16.xxxx.x... that we are looking for. It would also be useful to know if there is anything unique about the event you are creating - recurring meeting vs one-time meeting, timed vs all-day - and if the issue still reproduces in those differing scenarios